# Infinite loop even though it asks for input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I use scanner to ask for input, but it just prints out the prompt continuously.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
    public int remaining_sticks = 0;
    public int player1_sticks = 0;
    public int player2_sticks = 0;
    public boolean player = true;
    public boolean winner = false;

    public Game(){}

    public void game(){
        //set_remaining();
    player_turn();
    check_winner();
    }
    private String switch_player(){
        if (player==true){
            this.player = false;
            return("Player 1");
        }
        else{
            this.player = true;
            return("Player 2");
        }
    }
    public void set_remaining(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the game of sticks!\nHow many sticks are there on the board initially (10-100)?");
        this.remaining_sticks = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("\n");
        in.close();
    }
    public void check_winner(){
        if (remaining_sticks == 1 & player == true){
            this.winner = true;
            System.out.println("Player2 has won the game.");
        }
        else if (remaining_sticks == 1 & player == false){
            this.winner = true;
            System.out.println("Player1 has won the game.");
        }
    }
    public void player_turn(){
        System.out.println("There are "+Integer.toString(remaining_sticks)+" sticks on the board.\n"+switch_player()+": How many sticks do you take (1-3)?");
        if (this.player == true){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (in.hasNext()){
                String line = in.nextLine();
                player1_sticks = player1_sticks + Integer.parseInt(line);
                remaining_sticks = remaining_sticks - player1_sticks;
                System.out.println("There are "+Integer.toString(this.remaining_sticks)+" remaining.");
            }
            in.close();
        }
        else{
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (in.hasNext()){
                String line = in.nextLine();
                player2_sticks = player2_sticks + Integer.parseInt(line);
                remaining_sticks = remaining_sticks - player2_sticks;
                System.out.println("There are "+Integer.toString(this.remaining_sticks)+" remaining.");
            }
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I call it in the main class:

```
Game game = new Game();
    game.set_remaining();
    while (game.winner == false) {
        game.game();
```

Comment: You should follow the Java naming conventions, which are `lowerCamelCase`. Also, name your methods better. What does `game()` do? It should be renamed `tick()` or `turn()`.

Comment: Which is the "prompt" you are referring to? Please state to narrow down the issue.

Comment: You are instantiating a scanner without telling the compiler to wait for input...therefore the program execution continuously loops...
-->
int line = in.nextInt();